# adding jw player to drupal commerce/ ecommerce pro by themesnap

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, jwplayer, drupal-themes, commerce

I'm New to all this, but I have the e-commerce pro theme that I have modified a lot. I am on my last tweeks, but I'm getting stuck. I have the theme going good, products and everything work good, except for an issue that involves add a video to the product page. I can make a video page on it's own, it works well. I have added the field to the product set up page, so now you can upload the video to the product page, but it does not show up when the page is viewed. Maybe my css from my theme is blocking it? Any help or a point in the right direction would be awesome, sorry if this is not posted in the right place. Cheers-

Comment: Not nearly enough information.  Show us some code.  Console errors?

Comment: Ok, sorry.  I have the ecommercePro theme from Themesnap.  Everything is up to date and runs good.  [link]http://themesnap.com/theme-demos/ecommerce-pro/  There is the demo.  I have the JW Player module installed.  [link]http://drupal.org/project/jw_player  runs fine, I can make a page with video, I can add the upload field to the product page, it uploads, all looks ok yet when the page is viewed there is no video.  I think I need to edit the node--product.tpl.php file but not sure what to add..  Again, sorry for being such a noob :P

Comment: You can always use the JW Player Module? http://drupal.org/project/jwplayermodule

Comment: Thanks Eithan, I posted on the Longtail site this morning, that module does not work with Drupal 7.  Here is my post on that: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/31602/drupal-7-jwplayer-6-step-by-step

Comment: Video test page: 'code'
</div></div></div><div class="field field-name-field-video field-type-file field-label-above"><div class="field-label">video:&nbsp;</div><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><div class="jwplayer-video">
  <video id="a274315e1abede44d63005826249d1df" width="320" height="240" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <source src="http://localhost/ecommercepro/sites/default/files/MB4V_0.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
-----the other "product" page has nothing in the code referring to video. The test one used a "content type" I named "video"

Comment: Right. If you want to use a Drupal 7 mode, I believe a 3rd party plugin developer made one.

Comment: Seems any new field I add will not show up then the product page is viewed. Yet all the fields work and are present in the edit of the page. I have a node--product.tpl.php ..does that need to be edited to allow for the changes to be viewable?

Comment: Is there an example we can look at?